# Control the visibility of attributes on an attribute form using group box containers, based on values in CSV reference layer, using QGIS

Tags: qgis, qfield, qgis-expression

I’ve been using the following expression to replicate a value relation widget/cascading dropdown list, for a QField workspace template; it auto populates an attribute (Q1) with text from a CSV layer ('Habitat Options'), based on the selected value of another attribute ‘Baseline Habitat Type’ (i.e. when 'Baseline Habitat Type' = 'UKHAB' in the CSV layer 'Habitat Options', then populate the Q1 attribute with the corresponding value of the 'Question 1' field in the CSV layer:

```
attribute( get_feature( 'Habitat Options','UKHAB', current_value('Baseline Habitat Type')),'Question 1')
```

This works well, but I was hoping to use a similar expression to control the visibility of the attribute/questions on my attribute form when digitising, using group box containers. Sometimes the 'Question 1' attribute within the CSV layer is a blank cell (i.e. when it is not relevant to the particular 'Baseline Habitat Type' selected), in these instances I don't want the 'Q1' attribute to appear on my form when digitising. I've tried to control the visibility of the group box container using the following expression but it won't work:

```
 attribute(get_feature( 'Habitat Options','UKHAB', current_value('Baseline Habitat Type')),'Question 1')=''
```

I've also tried is null instead of ='' which didn't work either. I've searched for a solution to this online but haven't found one I understand. How can I get it to work?

Comment: First your syntax seem wrong, if you want to test for an empty string you should use single quote (so it should be  ....='' not ...="" ,as double quote are for field name ). If it still don't work try different syntax after the equal sign (like is null, or space (...=' ') )